# Visual Studio 2017 Installer is "Unable to download installation files"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I've just finished talking to the "Microsoft Support Chat" and he told me to post this here (i can't post it on the developercommunity forums because i need to click a button in the installer which isn't there at that stage).

When I'm trying to run the VS Enterprise 2017 installer (or any other edition) the installer cancels with the error message: "Unable to download installation files. Check your internet connection and try again."

What I tried so far:

- Running as Administrator
- Downloading the installer with a different browser
- Using the --layout option to download files first (same error message, no files downloaded)
- Installing the certificates
- Using the --update option before running the installer regularly
- Running the Windows 10 Windows Update Troubleshooter (couldn't identify the problem)
- Disabling Bitdefender Antivirus
- Multiple Reboots/Re-Downloads

One more thing that might be helpful is that quite a while back when i was installing "Cyber Ghost VPN" on the same machine i had trouble connecting using that application because a windows service that should've been active wasn't running.

Also I would've included the Logs from running the vscollect tool but i can't seem to figure out how to attach a file here. Do i have to upload it somewhere else and include the link or is there a way i can just attach the file here?

Comment: You can't attach files here.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a certificate issue, maybe your time and region are not set correctly, so the certificate is in a different date than the server. I followed this three spets a couple weeks ago and it worked.

1. Install the certificates, usually in "certificates" folder,(inside Layout folder).
2. Right-click each one to install it with administrator rigths.
   3.Run the installation file.

Comment: Maybe that wasn't clear from my post but i don't even get the layout folder. When i run the layout option it gives me the error without downloading any file. I've also tried downloading the files from a different PC and transferring them over and doing that (installing certificates and run installer again - also with option --noweb as i've seen this in a different post) but that didn't work either.